# Why there is Kv instead of Kd(derivative gain)?

Tags: pid-controller

I am reading documentation of Quanser VTOL(vertical take off and landing) trainer and i was studying PID control there,but strange enough i found the term "Kv" instead of "Kd" derivative gain(as shown highlighted in attached snapshot)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd have to ask the author, but "v" for "velocity" is an obvious choice even if it's not the one you'd make.

Comment: Velocity feedback is the time differential of the error. It's the same thing.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's not the same thing, and the documentation cited in the question does call out the difference "the measured velocity is used instead of the derivative of the error".  Another possible meaning of velocity gain would be a feed-forward term, if it were to use a velocity setpoint rather than a velocity estimate.

Comment: In fact, the diagram doesn't quite match equation 4.3

Comment: It's a newbie written paper comparing a std PID loop to some VTOL loop without correcting with the actual sensor inputs p, v, a.  Try reading the better method of control. "Adaptive neuro fuzzy inference system"

Comment: [Link for the document cited](https://www.lehigh.edu/~inconsy/lab/frames/me389/guidelines/mem01_files/QNET_VTOL_Exp08-Position_Student.pdf) . Presumably they're using a gyro measurement for velocity which is proportional to the derivative of error, iff the setpoint is static.

Answer (score 1):

Look at equation 4.3.

In both the proportional and integral term, the quantity \$ (\theta_d - \theta) \$ appears.  In the differential term, it's just \$ -k_v \dot{\theta} \$ not \$ k_v (\dot{\theta_d} - \dot{\theta}) \$

The text actually emphasized this to you in the sentence immediately following the part you highlighted.

Answer (score -1):

> I found the term \$K_v\$ instead of \$K_d\$ derivative gain

It's trivial enough: both terms seem to be used interchangeably in your text. The likely cause is that *v* is a time derivative. Sure it may be confusing, and I hate texts where no attention is paid to consistency.

Sometimes "authors" just copy material from other sources, or paraphrase it without making it consistent with the rest of the text. Here, the figure looks like it came from one source, and the equations came from another source, and nobody putting the two together had a iota of care about it :(

I have no idea why the question got downvoted. All of use were "confused undergrads" at one time or another :)

Comment: The author appears to be very carefully changing the notation to emphasize that there is a difference from the normal PID loop (however the figure is of a normal PID loop and uses normal notation).  And has directed the reader to "remark" the change.  (*Remark* is a verb meaning *take notice of*, see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remark)